# Does the book version of *Divergent* do the main characters face off in a one-on-one contest without interference?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, divergent

**(I'm wording this to avoid giving movie spoilers, but I'm asking for an answer with a book spoiler of sorts, so reader beware.)**

In the book version of *Divergent*, do the main characters have a prolonged physical contest without anyone interfering? If so, is there a reason why no one intervenes?

Spoiler explanation of my question:

> In the film, Tris and Four have a struggle while the bad guys watch. That they wait to see the outcome makes some sense. However, Tris seems to have several armed allies right outside that location, who don't seem to be doing anything but possibly attempting first aid or taking last rights. It seems like they could have taken the opportunity to rush in and shoot the bad guys, and I didn't see any reason why they didn't. Does the book have a different situation, or explain why they didn't come help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Book spoiler as requested:

> In the book version, the fight between Tris and Four is the [Falling Action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dramatic_structure#Falling_action) of the story, whereas in the movie it's only the lead in to the fight with Jeanine and the bad guys.
>
>
>  Tris is with her father, Marcus, Caleb, and Peter.  Peter is their prisoner, and so when they reach the elevator Tris:
>
>
>  *I hand one gun to Caleb and slide the other one under my belt.
>
>
>
>
>  "I think you and Marcus should stay here with him," I say, jerking my head toward Peter.  "He'll just slow us down.  Make sure no one comes after us."*
>
>
>  Tris and her father then take the elevator up.  In their fight with the guards, he is mortally wounded and she continues on to find Four alone in the control room.
>
>
>  In the book, we don't see Jeanine at the end, and the bad guy guards in place were trying to prevent Tris and company from reaching Four (well, the control room, which happens to be where Four was).  She got past them, the others engaged them.

The end answer to your question is, all the supporting characters were tied up with each other, leaving the two characters alone for their battle of will.

Comment: Aha, thanks! That situation makes a lot more sense.